# Function to get minimum of three or more arguments

Tags: c, minimum, math.h

In the `<math.h>` library in C, the function `fmin(x,y)` returns the minimum value of the two arguments x and y, as documented for instance in [the C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmin/).

However, is there a similar function `fminimum(a,b,c,...x,y,z)` available that finds the minimum of three or more arguments of the same data type?

Comment: Your title says "in C" but your tags include C++. Are you allowing for a C++ solution?

Comment: @mbratch ok, sorry, only C at this point

Comment: Using varargs it's possible to do this, but you must give extra argument telling how many numbers you are passing, or using some special value such as `NaN` to indicate the last number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old fashioned way...

```
int arr[] = { 1, 3, 6, 100, 50, 72 };

int min_array( int arr[], int len )
{
    int min = arr[0];

    for ( int i = 1; i < len; i++ )
        if ( arr[i] < min )
            min = arr[i];

    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**Note**: The question was originally tagged C++. The original answer works for C++ only, but I have provided a C solution that follows the same principles.

The idea is that pair of pointers representing the start and one past the end of a range is passed to the function, and a pointer to the minimum element is returned.

```
int* min_element(int *start, int *end)
{
    if (start == end) return end;

    int *min = start++;
    for (; start != end; ++start)
        if (*start < *min) min = start;

    return min;
}
```

Usage:

```
int data[] = {1, 5, 3, 66, 4, 81, 23, 2, 6};
int * min = min_element(data, data + 9);
if (min != data + 9)
{
  // range was not empty, min value is *min
}
```

---

**Original `C++` answer**
There is [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), which gives you an iterator to the minimum element in a range specified by a pair of iterators.

```
int arr[] = { 3,1,6,8,9,34,17,4,8};
auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

**Edit 2**: From a deleted answer, C++11 has an [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) overload which takes an `initializer_list`, so you can say

```
auto minval = std::min({a, b, c, x, y, z});
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` etc. are all of one type supporting `operator<`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP only wants `C`

Comment: @mbratch too bad they originally tagged the question as C++ then :)

Comment: @juanchopanza indeed, that's why I asked the OP in a comment.

Comment: @mbratch, I figured they meant C++ if they were using "the C++ reference" :/

Comment: @chris yeah, it wasn't a very well-worded question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with "arbitrary number of arguments" is how do you know how many there are.

The `std::min` and `std::min_element` work around this by working on containers - in other words, we know how many thanks to the container object itself knows how many.

In plain C, you can't really do that. So there needs to be some other method.

One way would be to use `<cstdarg>`, and either mark the end with a special value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

int countargs(int arg, ...)
{
    if (arg == -1)
    return 0;

    int count = 1;   // arg is not -1, so we have at least one arg.
    va_list vl;
    int cur;
    va_start(vl, arg);
    for(;;)
    {
    cur = va_arg(vl, int);
    if(cur == -1)
        break;
    count++;
    }
    va_end(vl);
    return count;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Should give 0: " << countargs(-1) << endl;
    cout << "Should give 1: " << countargs(1, -1) << endl; 
    cout << "Should give 3: " << countargs(1, 2, 3, -1) << endl;
    cout << "Should give 6: " << countargs(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, -1) << endl;
    cout << "Should give 12: " << countargs(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, -1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above doesn't show how to get the `min` value, but it shouldn't be that hard to figure out. It's also C++, but doesn't rly on any special C++ features.

The alternative to "marking the end" is to pass the number of elements to the function itself.

Of course, if the arguments are in an array, the real solution is to just iterate through them. And if there aren't that many, you can of course use:

```
v = min(a, min(b, min(c, d)));;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only libc function which could do this would do much more, as it would sort, which can be considered an overkill. It's `qsort()`.